# Unable add vm extension dynatrace one agent using azure bicep though azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-bicep, dynatrace

unable to add vm extension dynatrace one agent using azure bicep. Getting below error

{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"OperationNotAllowed","message":"VM Extension with publisher 'dynatrace.ruxit' and type 'oneAgentWindows' does not support setting enableAutomaticUpgrade property to true."},{"code":"OperationNotAllowed","message":"VM Extension with publisher 'dynatrace.ruxit' and type 'oneAgentWindows' does not support setting enableAutomaticUpgrade property to true."}]}

i tried to deploy azure bicep (vm extension dynatrace one agent windows) though azure devops pipe line.

iam getting below error

{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"OperationNotAllowed","message":"VM Extension with publisher 'dynatrace.ruxit' and type 'oneAgentWindows' does not support setting enableAutomaticUpgrade property to true."},{"code":"OperationNotAllowed","message":"VM Extension with publisher 'dynatrace.ruxit' and type 'oneAgentWindows' does not support setting enableAutomaticUpgrade property to true."}]}

Answer (score 0):

According to this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/automatic-extension-upgrade#supported-extensions) Automatic Extension upgrade is only supported for below extensions in VM:-

> Supported extensions Automatic Extension Upgrade supports the
> following extensions (and more are added periodically): Azure
> Automation Hybrid Worker extension - Linux and Windows Dependency
> Agent – Linux and Windows Application Health Extension – Linux and
> Windows Guest Configuration Extension – Linux and Windows Key Vault –
> Linux and Windows Azure Monitor Agent Log Analytics Agent for Linux
> Azure Diagnostics extension for Linux DSC extension for Linux

And Dynatrace one agent extension is not part of the list above.

I referred this [Dynatrace official document](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/setup-and-configuration/setup-on-cloud-platforms/microsoft-azure-services/azure-integrations/azure-vm#install-dynatrace-oneagent-vm-extension-via-an-arm-template) ARM template and it does not include `-EnableAutomaticUpgrade  $true` property.

Also, What you can try is list the dynatrace publisher and version by running the command below and try using different publisher and version of Dynatrace to enable automatic upgrade, If it fails, The unfortunately it is not supported:-

Command [reference](https://community.dynatrace.com/t5/Cloud-platforms/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Azure-VM-extension-installation-with/m-p/63866)

> ```bash
> az vm extension image list --location westeurope -p dynatrace.ruxit -o table
> ```
>
> **Output:-**
>
> [image]

One more workaround as mentioned in this [MS Forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1161491/vm-extension-with-publisher-microsoft-sqlserver-ma) answers for similar error code for SQL not Dynatrace is below:-

Register the **AutomaticExtensionUpgradePreview** feature in your Azure subscription as mentioned in this MS Fr by running the command below:-

> ```
> Register-AzProviderFeature -FeatureName AutomaticExtensionUpgradePreview -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Compute
> Get-AzProviderFeature -FeatureName AutomaticExtensionUpgradePreview  -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Compute
> ```

**Output:-**

[image]